# apt-get install behind proxy - Failed to fetch

Tags: 18.04, apt, updates, proxy

This is yet another question regarding the error message `E: Failed to fetch ...` (example in Note 2 below).
What makes this question different (I guess) from the others I have seen is the following.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04LTS, behind a proxy.
I had a lot of packages with available updates (more than 200, I guess).

  I could update many of the packages with no problem, and I ended up with 48 that I cannot install.

All of the packages not installed belong to `bionic-updates/universe` or `bionic-updates/main`.
And most are related to `java`, `jdk`, `linux`, `systemd`.
The complete list is in Note 1 below.
But there are packages from `bionic-updates/universe` and `bionic-updates/main` that I can install (I just installed `qemu` and `bsdutils`).

**How is it possible that some of the packages can be installed and some cannot?**

**What is a possible solution (other than connecting the PC without a proxy)?**

---

**Notes**:

1. **Complete list of packages not installed**

   ```
   ant ant-optional apport apport-gtk fwupd fwupdate fwupdate-signed gettext gettext-base jarwrapper junit4 libasm-java libcommons-collections3-java libcommons-compress-java libcommons-httpclient-java libdb5.3 libdb5.3-java libdb5.3-java-jni libecj-java libequinox-osgi-java libhsqldb1.8.0-java libjetty9-java libnss-systemd libobjenesis-java libpam-systemd libservlet3.1-java libsystemd0 libtomcat8-java linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic openjdk-11-jdk openjdk-11-jdk-headless openjdk-11-jre openjdk-11-jre-headless openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jdk-headless openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jre-headless python-pip-whl python3-pip snapd systemd
   ```

This was obtained with

```
$ sudo apt list --upgradable 2> /dev/null | sed 's/\/.*//' | tail +2 | sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/ /g'
```

To find which repo each one belonged, I used (`printf "%30s"...` helps visualizing in columns)

```
$ for p in $(sudo apt list --upgradable 2> /dev/null | sed 's/\/.*//' | tail +2 | sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/ /g') ; do printf "%30s" $p ; apt policy $p 2> /dev/null | tail +6 | head -1 ; done
```

This generates output like

```
                       ant        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
```

2. **Sample error**

```
    $ sudo apt-get install apport
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    The following packages will be upgraded:
      apport
    1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 46 not upgraded.
    Need to get 125 kB of archives.
    After this operation, 20,5 kB of additional disk space will be used.
    Ign:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 apport all 2.20.9-0ubuntu7.17
    Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 apport all 2.20.9-0ubuntu7.17
      403  URLBlockDownload [IP: xxx.xxx.xxx3.xxx 80]
    E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apport/apport_2.20.9-0ubuntu7.17_all.deb  403  URLBlockDownload [IP: 10.1.33.101 80]
    E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

3. **EDIT: output "requested" in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1276241/226614) is here.**

```
    $ find /etc/apt/ -name "*.list" -exec grep -iq http {} \; -exec egrep -v '^#|^$' {} \; | uniq 
    deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
    deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
    deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
    deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
    deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
    deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
    deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
    deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
    deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
    deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
    deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
    deb https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu/ bionic main
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like enterprise firewall is blocking certain urls of apt, that's why you are not able to download packages via apt. You need to get all URLs white listed in firewall mentioned in source list. You need to have admin access of firewall or kindly contact network administrator.

As Alternative option, try to connect system directly with another internet source like USB Dongle or Mobile.

Comment: Would you mind detailing what is the possible form/mechanism/configuration files (assuming Linux in the proxy) of white/blacklisting that allows me to install some packages from a given repo and not some others?
Do you mean that the filtering is possibly based on file names, as part of the target (URL) of the apt command, and not only on the site or even directory in the repo?

That looks very strange to me.

Comment: Here firewall config depends on which firewall is being used.

Comment: It has nothing to do with linux proxy at all on your local client or desktop.

Comment: Here you need to understand rootcause. If it blocked by firewall, you would not able to download at all. No matter whatever application or command line command you try.

Comment: Having solved [this independent question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1276485/how-do-apt-and-wget-find-uri-locations-in-the-web-and-fetch-files-how-are-these), I could perform the further test I meant to.
And this test supports your suggestion.

Comment: In my opinion, allowing url via firewall would be ultimate solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is an effort to give a more solid basis to the suggestion in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1276426/226614).
It mentions that
firewall filtering is the culprit, and that it is based on the full URI used for each package, including the package name itself.
That *might* explain why some packages from a given repo can be installed and some others cannot.
To test this, I have obtained the URIs for all packages that I cannot install with `--print-uris` (see full contrived command line in Note 1 below), and for package `yudit-common` which I don't have, and I could later install.
Then I tried `wget`ting those URIs.

For each one of the packages that I was not able to install, the `.deb` file for either that package or one of its dependencies produced

```
$ wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/ant/ant-optional_1.10.5-3~18.04_all.deb
--2020-09-22 10:18:35--  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/ant/ant-optional_1.10.5-3~18.04_all.deb
Resolving proxy-myserver (proxy-myserver)... xx.xx.xx.xx
Connecting to proxy-myserver (proxy-myserver)|xx.xx.xx.xx|:xx... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 403 URLBlockDownload
2020-09-22 10:18:35 ERROR 403: URLBlockDownload.
```

**This would more strongly confirm the proposal.**

---

**Notes**:

1. **Obtaining full URIs for packages** (and also trying `wget` here)

```
    for p in $(sudo apt list --upgradable 2> /dev/null | sed 's/\/.*//' | tail +2 | sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/ /g') ; do for uri in $(apt install --print-uris $p 2> /dev/null | sed -n '/^After this operation/ { :a; n; p; ba; }' | awk '{ print substr($1,2,length($1)-2) }') ; echo "uri=${uri}" ; wget ${uri} ; done ; done
```

Comment: Can you ssh to a server outside the firewall and use that to circumvent the firewall?  Have you talked to the admin of the firewall to ask them about the reason for this URL being blocked?  You might be able to bypass the firewall, but if the firewall admin finds out he might not be happy, to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

Proxy server can be set up different ways. One way is to allow access to specific sites is by wildcard domain or vice versa. If admin or environment for this is even more paranoid it is possible make exceptions even more granual allowing access to specific sites by regex formulas to specific URI-s.

What is the output of
`apt-get update` does it have any errors?

Comment: I don't have admin access to the proxy. I do not even know if they run under Linux/Ubuntu/etc.
Would you have a way to at least trying to test this from my machine?
E.g. by comparing the response to some commands when connecting to repos that provide packages that I can install vs. packages that I cannot install.

Comment: you try those urls out in your computer which should give hint if problem is on your side or url is denied in proxy server.

Comment: I have posted in the OP the output of the command you suggest. I am not sure what to do with that information.

Comment: try to open the given URLs in your browser, if one of them is not opening/responding then mention it here.

Comment: Note that, as edited in the OP, there are packages from `bionic-updates/universe` and `bionic-updates/main` that I can install, so the source of the problem is not likely that I cannot access the URL.
Will try anyway.
PS: Why did you remove the command you suggested?

Comment: I did not find a way to pass the proxy with either chrome or firefox, so I cannot try what you suggested.

Comment: I overthinked a bit with my first debugging command line. Basically if apt-get update doesn't run through then you shouldn't be able to install anything besides stuff that is cached to your local disk.

Comment: As I said, that is not either the case I can install some packages, and some others not. And I am certain the packages I can install are not cached in my local disk.

Comment: What is the output of `apt update` then ?