# How do apt and wget find URI locations in the web and fetch files? How are these methods different?

Tags: apt, package-management, wget, domain-server

I am using Ubuntu 18.04LTS, behind a proxy.
This question was sparked by (but it is completely independent of) [apt-get install behind proxy - Failed to fetch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1275269/apt-get-install-behind-proxy-failed-to-fetch)

When I check the location of package `yudit-common` with `apt install --print-uris` (e.g.; actually, as a prerequisite for `feh`), I get `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/y/yudit/yudit-common_2.9.6-7_all.deb` as the location in the web of the `deb` file.
See Note 1 below.

Then when I install `yudit-common`, everything works fine, which means **my PC knows where is the `deb` file** `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/y/yudit/yudit-common_2.9.6-7_all.deb` in the web, **and it can download it** prior to installing.
See Note 2 below.

But if I try to `wget` the file, **my PC doesn't even know where is the `deb` file** (in this case, of course it would not be able to get it).
See Note 3 below.

**Where are `apt` and `wget` looking for the information?**

**Can I force `wget` to use the same domain lookup as `apt`?**

**In the case it is a firewall who is letting `apt` succeed in knowing ip addresses and pulling files from the web, and precluding `wget` from doing that, can I somehow "channel" `wget` requests via `apt`?**

---

**Notes**

1. **Location of the `.deb` package file**

```
    $ apt install --print-uris feh 2> /dev/null
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    The following additional packages will be installed:
      yudit-common
    Suggested packages:
      yudit-doc yudit
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
      feh yudit-common
    0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 51 not upgraded.
    Need to get 1.760 kB of archives.
    After this operation, 9.775 kB of additional disk space will be used.
    'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/y/yudit/yudit-common_2.9.6-7_all.deb' yudit-common_2.9.6-7_all.deb 1637644 MD5Sum:987ef69fa59b1c3034bfa28955e612d9
    'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/feh/feh_2.23.2-1build1_amd64.deb' feh_2.23.2-1build1_amd64.deb 122020 MD5Sum:b5f42ee280ee4aada1cbd93ec0007e68
```

2. **Installing `yudit-common`**

```
    $ sudo apt-get install yudit-common
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Suggested packages:
      yudit-doc yudit
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
      yudit-common
    0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 51 not upgraded.
    Need to get 1.638 kB of archives.
    After this operation, 9.411 kB of additional disk space will be used.
    Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 yudit-common all 2.9.6-7 [1.638 kB]
    Fetched 1.638 kB in 9s (174 kB/s)      
    Selecting previously unselected package yudit-common.
    (Reading database ... 488875 files and directories currently installed.)
    Preparing to unpack .../yudit-common_2.9.6-7_all.deb ...
    Unpacking yudit-common (2.9.6-7) ...
    Setting up yudit-common (2.9.6-7) ...
```

3. **`wget`ting `yudit-common` `.deb` file**

```
    $ wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/y/yudit/yudit-common_2.9.6-7_all.deb
    --2020-09-20 06:32:21--  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/y/yudit/yudit-common_2.9.6-7_all.deb
    Resolving us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)... failed: Name or service not known.
    wget: unable to resolve host address ´us.archive.ubuntu.com´
```

4. **Interesting**:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168584/wget-is-unable-to-resolve-host-address-80-of-the-time

Comment: #3 look like a DNS or other networking failure, not magic. When I tried it, it worked properly.

Comment: @user535733 - But why would this fail for `wget` and not for `apt`?
Note that I am behind a proxy.

Comment: It's not `apt` vs. `wget`, it's DNS lookups at Time 1 vs. DNS lookups at Time 2.

Comment: @waltinator - I'm sorry, I don't understand the expression "DNS lookups at Time 1". Therefore I don't understand this as an explanation for any of the two related questions in the OP.

Comment: A "DNS lookup" is how a site's name (`us.archive.ubuntu.com`) is translated to an IP address. "Time 1" and "Time 2" are different times. I'm suggesting that your environment changed in between. `/etc/resolv.conf`, `dnsmasq`, connectivity,...

Comment: @waltinator - I know what a DNS and DNS lookup is. 
I was not understanding your conjecture about the change of environment over time.

I tested repeatedly
`sudo apt-get install yudit-common`, 
`sudo apt-get remove yudit-common`, 
`sudo apt-get clean yudit-common`, 
and
`wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/y/yudit/yudit-common_2.9.6-7_all.deb`.
 
It turns out that `apt-get` always works, `wget` always fails.
So I doubt environment is constantly changing to produce the alternating success failure.

What do you think?

Comment: @waltinator - It seems the "provider" (whatever that is) of DNS lookup for `wget` is not the same as for `apt`.

Comment: @waltinator  I found the answer, and I posted it... it was quite simple!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact relation and interoperation of my PC, the proxy, the firewall, and the DNS server.

But I found that the cause `apt` was succeding in my case, and `wget` was not, is that I was missing a proper configuration of the proxy for `wget`.
When I added file `~/.wgetrc` with

```
http_proxy = http://username:password@proxy:port
ftp_proxy = http://username:password@proxy:port
proxy_user = username
proxy_password = password 
use_proxy = on
```

It started working. (Note it is somewhat insecure, as the password is stored in plain text... I wonder if there is any way to have `wget` ask for the password; or perhaps setting a global `.wgetrc` in a directory with the same level of security as `apt.conf`).
On the other hand, `apt` relies on `/etc/apt/apt.conf`, which was in place.

As for the questions:

**Where are `apt` and `wget` looking for the information?**

Part of the sequence involves setting the proxy.
`apt` and `wget` have different mechanisms for that, as mentioned above (I know one can set environment variables as well, and that would work at least for `wget`).

**Can I force `wget` to use the same domain lookup as `apt`?**

I conceive a caveman-way... parsing `apt.conf` and using that info for `wget`.
Perhaps there is something cleaner.

**In the case it is a firewall who is letting `apt` succeed in knowing ip addresses and pulling files from the web, and precluding `wget` from doing that, can I somehow "channel" `wget` requests via `apt`?**

In the light of findings above, this question is replaced by the previous one.

Comment: If you need to set a proxy, it's best to set it via environment variables http_proxy and ftp_proxy. Then all programs should be able to use them.

Comment: As for your question about the domain lookup, if proxy is set, neither apt nor wget (nor any other program that uses the proxy) does the domain lookup on the target domain. It onl does the domain lookup of the proxy, and then passes the target domain name to proxy which does the lookup. On the other hand, if proxy is not set, the program does the DNS lookup by itself, using your system resolver configuration (```/etc/resolv.conf```).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your Ubuntu system knows where to find .debs. It's a three-step process.

1. Your system knows where archives (*sources*) are located. Its in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

   ```
   $ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
   deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main universe
   deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main universe
   deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main universe
   ```

   - The initial *sources* are placed by the Ubuntu installer. You can change these sources; it's just a text file owned by root. However, you also risk breaking your system, so be sure you know how to restore the originals.
2. Apt keeps a database of all known packages from all known *sources*. Name, description, version, size, URI, etc. Apt uses it's database to calculate available upgrades, and to know the URIs to fetch packages from.

   Each time you run `sudo apt update`, apt downloads a Release file from each source, and uses that Release file to updates apt's database.

   - The database is at /var/lib/apt/lists. It's designed to be machine-readable, not human-readable. Use apt commands (`apt search` or `apt list` or `apt-cache`, etc) to query the database.
   - This is why most instructions say to run `apt update` right before installing new software -- so apt's database has the correct URI.
3. When you tell apt to `sudo apt install foo`, apt consults it's database to look for the right version, uninstalled dependencies, and the URIs of all the packages that it needs.

Comment: Even if generally useful, I know this explanation.
But I am not seeing here an explanation of who is in charge of telling `apt` where to find `us.archive.ubuntu.com` in the web (which ip), and then why that same actor isn't conveying the same information to `wget`.
I guess that would answer the question.

Comment: DNS lookup (resolver) is responsible. I'm simply going to repeat what @waltinator said: You had a coincidental network problem when using wget, not a wget or Ubuntu problem. Without the (non-Ubuntu) network problem, wget works as you expect.

Comment: Please see my comment below @waltinator.
I doubt the coincidence you mention is the cause.

Comment: See my first comment from your question: When I tried wget on the URL, it works properly.

Comment: Ok, I understand `wget` *should* work, and then there is something "strange" in my case.
That is what I'm trying to find out, and what I am asking about.

Comment: Unfortunately, your Question above seems a classic [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You have some kind of network problem, but instead of asking "*How should I troubleshoot this?*" you jumped past troubleshooting into "*How do apt and wget work?*"  Consider opening a fresh question  on troubleshooting.

Comment: Interesting... I didn't know about the naming, and I partially agree. Adding to this:
1) X is asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1275269/apt-get-install-behind-proxy-failed-to-fetch), linked at the top.
2) An answer to Y (this OP) may not solve X, and I do not mean it. That is why "it is completely independent of..."
Here, I want to learn a little on under-the-hood stuff.
I guess that is not against the objectives of SE... and I guess this OP is well formulated, there is some prior work/effort on my side, and it may be useful for others.
I welcome anyone helping with X as well.

Comment: I found the answer, and I posted it... it was quite simple!